# Order by XML attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-order-by

I have the following table

```
EntityID   | Data
-----------+-----------
1          | <xml data>
2          | <xml data>
3          | <xml data>
```

Where XML DATA looks like this:

```
<Qualifications>
  <Qualification QualificationName="Has Dr's degree" Remark="Yes" />
  <Qualification QualificationName="ASP.NET Experience" Remark="1 Year" />
  <Qualification QualificationName="Sex" Remark="M" />
</Qualifications>
```

I'd like to have the ability to order by remark for a particular QualificationName

SELECT * FROM Table
....
ORDER BY 'ASP.NET Experience'

P.S.
Potencially I can change XML to something like this to make things simplier

```
<Qualifications>
  <Has Dr's degree>Yes</Has Dr's degree>
  <ASP.NET Experience>1 Year</ASP.NET Experience>
  <Sex>M</Sex>
</Qualifications>
```

UPD1: For case when user wants to order by 'ASP.NET Experience' qualification The expected result would be like this:

```
EntityID   | Data
-----------+-----------
3          | <xml data>
1          | <xml data>
2          | <xml data>
```

Because EntityID 3 has Remark '1 year' EntityID 1 has remark '2 years' and EntityID 2 has remark '3 years' inside XML column for 'ASP.NET Experience' qualification

Comment: Can you show some expected result?

Comment: @Darka added expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming @QualificationName identifies the particular  node you want to order by this will give you the value of the Remark.

```
declare @xml xml; set @xml = '<Qualifications>
    <Qualification QualificationName="Has Dr%quot;s degree" Remark="Yes" />
    <Qualification QualificationName="ASP.NET Experience" Remark="1 Year" />
    <Qualification QualificationName="Sex" Remark="M" />
</Qualifications>'

declare @Qualification nvarchar(100); set @Qualification = 'ASP.NET Experience'

select @xml.value('(//Qualifications/Qualification[@QualificationName=sql:variable("@Qualification")]/@Remark)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
```

Comment: I need to order by Remark value for a single particular QualificationName. I don't know this QualificationName before user selects that.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed your xml as:

```
<Qualifications>
  <HasDrsdegree>Yes</HasDrsdegree>
  <ASPNETExperience>2</ASPNETExperience>
  <Sex>M</Sex>
</Qualifications>
```

I hope this query will resolve your problem, this query results one extra column which you can ignore but this will solve you problem for complete table in one go.

```
Select EntityID,Data,T2.Loc.value('.','int') as 'experience'
from [yourtablename]
cross apply Data.nodes('/Qualifications/ASPNETExperience') as T2(Loc)
order by experience
```